# How to search for string that contains all phrases with egrep

Tags: linux, bash, grep

```
egrep -c LOGIN wrapper.log|egrep -c failed wrapper.log \
|egrep -c '[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}' wrapper.log\
|egrep -cv mymathworks wrapper.log|egrep -cv nacmpa wrapper.log > failed-login.txt
```

Is what I have currently. I need to only return the number of lines in one file with LOGIN, failed, an ip address pattern, and not contain mymathworks or nacmpa.

The current regular expression only returns the number of lines in a file without nacmpa.

Comment: Learn to debug your code by building it up one cmd at a time. What is output of `egrep -c LOGIN wrapper.log`? Then What is the output of `egrep -c LOGIN wrapper.log|egrep -c failed wrapper.log`? Does that output make sense, if not, fix that before piling more stuff on (-; OK? Also see my comment below about multiple references to `wrapper.log` (that doesn't make sense, generally). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The `-c` option of egrep prints only the count, instead of the content i.e., after `LOGIN` count is got, the `failed` count will *never* match (since any number will not match the text `failed`). Breaking Your pipeline into parts may help You work it out.

Comment: I wasn't clear in my post. I only want the count instead of the content. The goal is to append the number of lines in the file that meet all of the criteria specified. It should be 801708 lines. Could you elaborate on what you mean by breaking the pipeline into parts? Right now when I run the whole script the only count I get is for -cv nacmpa

Comment: Also, the O.P. has listed the `wrapper.log` after each `egrep target` but connected with `|`s. Shouldn't it be just one `egrep srchTarget file | egrep anotherSrchTarg | egrep .... > outFile` ? Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You should only list the input file (wrapper.log) on the *first* `egrep` in the pileline, and you should only give the `-c` option on the *last* one. Also, I'm pretty sure you could simplify this to use fewer pipeline stages.

Long answer: To see what's going wrong, let's look at what happens at the first couple of stages of the pipeline. The first command in the pipeline is

```
egrep -c LOGIN wrapper.log
```

...which searches wrapper.log and prints the number of lines that contain "LOGIN". Not the lines that contain "LOGIN", just the count of lines.

The next command is

```
egrep -c failed wrapper.log
```

...which searches wrapper.log and prints the number of lines that contain "failed". It does not read from its input, so the output of the first `egrep` gets completely ignored. Even if it did read it, it'd only have a count of lines, so there'd be no way to tell how many of those lines *also* contained "failed".

Solution: remove `-c` from the first `egrep` so it prints the actual matching lines, and remove `wrapper.log` from the second so that it searches the output from the first `egrep` rather than going back and re-reading the original file. The same problem occurs all the other stages of the pipeline, so you need to remove `wrapper.log` from all but the first (so the others actually read from the pipeline), and remove `-c` from all but the last (so you only take the count after all filtering has been done).

But as I said, I suspect the pipeline can be simplified quite a bit. Do "LOGIN", "failed", and the IP address always occur in the same order in the line? If so, make a single pattern that includes all of them. For "mymathworks" and "nacmpa", you can remove both at once with the pattern `mymathworks|nacmpa`. So you should be able to use something like this:

```
egrep 'LOGIN.*failed.*[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}' wrapper.log \
| egrep -cv 'mymathworks|nacmpa'
```

You may need to adjust the first pattern, depending on the order or the elements, and possibly what should be between them.